# Can a Java Singleton object be garbage collected only in part?

Tags: java, android, memory, garbage-collection, singleton

As far as I know, a Java singleton object can't be garbage collected except if the context that loaded this class (class loader) is itself eligible for garbage collection.

**Question #1:**
Is that right or is there another case it might be garbage collected?

In my app I have an Android Activity creating a singleton object. When the device runs out of memory while my app is on the background, if I try to open it and bring it back to the foreground I see that the singleton object has been destroyed and it's reinitialized.

**Question #2:**
If memory must be freed and a singleton object is garbage collected, is there any case where the singleton object might not get garbage collected totally and instead only some of its static variables will be garbage collected?

Comment: What do you mean you have an activity creating a singleton?

Comment: Probably easier to share the `Activity` and "singleton" code.

Comment: @MikkelT what I mean is that for example in my main activity's onCreate function I create and initialise an instance of a singleton object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my app I have an Android Activity creating a singleton object. When the device runs out of memory while my app is on the background, if I try to open it and bring it back to the foreground I see that the singleton object has been destroyed and it's reinitialized.

Yes. This has zip squat to do with 'garbage collection'. That's android unloading your entire app, which is very different.

> If memory must be freed and a singleton object is garbage collected, is there any case where the singleton object might not get garbage collected totally and instead only some of its static variables will be garbage collected?

Thus, this question is mostly a non sequitur.

There are 2 completely different mechanisms at work:

1. There's some free CPU cycles and/or some memory pressure, so do a bit of garbage collection. You won't notice any of this - if you can witness it in source code, it won't get garbage collected.
2. That isn't good enough / a different process is being started on the device and garbage collecting running processes stands no snowball's chance in freeing enough. In that case, your *entire* android app gets straight up unloaded. You get hard killed, and the next time your app gets attention (user runs it, or you have some hook that triggers), your app is reloaded, from scratch.

There is therefore no half-unloading. Whatever the garbage collector does is by definition not observable (if it had been it wouldn't be collected), and if your app gets unloaded, the whole thing goes away.

Comment: It's also worth adding that if you create an instance of your singleton and your app has a reference to it, it will not be eligible for garbage collection anyway. The GC will only remove objects from the heap if they are no longer referenced by anything else. It needs to unreachable in order to be eligible for collection.